# Returned values from Gaussian random number generator

Tags: c, random, gaussian

I am writing my first code in C. The project is a molecular dynamics code simulating particles bouncing around in an infinitely repeating box (periodic boundary conditions). Up to this point I have been loading the particle positions and velocities with pre-set values. It is time to add some (pseudo) randomness to my simulation. I found the following gaussian random number generating function online and after some modifications (the original author used drand48() which I could not get to work) I have the gaussian() function returning some numbers. For now I am not modifying the returned values to jive with the simulation; I just want to make sure I am getting new values each time.

I understand that I need to incorporate a seed for rand() such as srand(time(NULL)).
When srand(time(NULL)) is commented out, I get the same 20 random numbers each time I run the simulation, however when the statement is included, I get the same pair of random numbers 10 times. How can I properly initialize a seed for rand()?

```
/* function for gaussian random variables */
double gaussian()
{
    static int    have = 0;
    static double x2;
    double fac, y1, y2, x1;

    if ( have == 1 )  /* already one available ? */
    {
        have = 0;
        return x2;
    } 
    else 
    {
        /* generate a pair of random variables */
        /* srand(time(NULL)); */
        y1 = (double)rand() / RAND_MAX ;
        y2 = (double)rand() / RAND_MAX ;
        fac = sqrt(-2*log(y1));
        have = 1;
        x1 = fac*sin(2*M_PI*y2); /* x1 and x2 are now gaussian */
        x2 = fac*cos(2*M_PI*y2); /* so store one */
        return x1;               /* and return the other. */
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm sure a dozen people have already pointed out your obvious error of putting srand() inside your function. If this is something you really need to do (and not just an exercise), a MUCH faster way to calculate normal variates is called the Ziggurat algorithm. My public domain [ojrandlib](http://github.com/lcrocker/ojrandlib) does that.

Answer (score 1):

You should not call `srand(time(NULL))` each time you want to generate random numbers - call it once only, at the start of your `main()` function.

Answer (score 1):

You only need to call srand() once for your entire program so put it near the top of your main function or somewhere else convenient in the early part of your program.

The reason you're seeing the same pairs of numbers is most likely because you're calling your gaussian() function in a tight loop such that each call to time() is returning the same value and therefore resetting the random number generator to the same point; hence it gives you the same 2 numbers.

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <time.h>
//…
srand((unsigned)time(NULL));
//set a seed only once
//use rand()
```

however,rand() always generates pseudo-random number.